# is it possible to create Highchart polar chart which has x-axis at center rather than at circumference

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to create a polar column chart.
This chart has to show a stacked column.
this was simple but the real thing is I'm getting the x-axis & labels for the polar chart outside the chart at its circumference, but I want them to be inside at the center. Is it achievable ?

Thanks for your time

Comment: Why don't you show us what you have done so far, perhaps in a jsfiddle ?

Comment: I didn't do much, using the wind rose example http://jsfiddle.net/QgUgW/ , I tried using opposite property for the xAxis but failed to move it to center.

Comment: I would normally move the xAxis labels using the labels:{x:-10} type property, but the offset isn't being mapped properly in polar mode. Possibly a bug ?

Comment: I don't want just labels to move inside , I want the entire xAxis to come at the center like an opposite axis.

Comment: Could you show some kind of mockup, how this should look like..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not directly supported, but possible to achieve.

We need to create one extra fake series and axis for that one. Then using offset we can move main axis to the center. The last thing is to calculate min for yAxis, to make sure that columns won't starting from the inside.

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    series: [{
        data: [12,13,14,15,5,17]  
    }, {
        data: [13,15,4,12,14,16]   
    }, {
        data: [1,15,13,4,14,16]   
    },{
        data: [13,15,3,12,1,16]   
    },  {
        data: [null,null,null,null,null,null],
        xAxis: 1
    }],
    chart: {
        polar: true,
        type: 'column'
    },

    xAxis: [{
        offset: 120,
        tickInterval: 1,
        tickmarkPlacement: 'on'
    }, {
        lineWidth: 0,
        tickInterval: 1,
        labels: {
            enabled: false
        }
    }],

    yAxis: {
        min: -35,
        endOnTick: false,
        showLastLabel: true,
        title: {
            text: null
        },
        labels: {
            align: 'center',
            formatter: function () {
                if(this.value >= 0 ){
                    return this.value + '%';
                } else {
                    return '';
                }
            }
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            stacking: 'normal',
        }
    }
});
```

Example for you: http://jsfiddle.net/QgUgW/4/

Comment: you have seen the stacked column in the image, is that possible with highchart?

Comment: can you please tell me why do we need that extra series with null data and an extra axis because when I've removed the secondary x-axis and the null series then also it was looking fine.

Comment: You don't have straight lines from the inside. It's only reason for a second axis and an extra series.

Comment: I want the entire center to be filled with a particular color. is it possible? at the same time i need a label at the center. can get the x-axis title at the center like a label

Comment: You can use chart.Renderer.text() to add text in the center. To fill plotting area use plotBackgroundColor/Image or you can try to use plotBands.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the offset property: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.offset

But this results in a confusing chart.
Polar charts are usually confusing enough as it is..

Comment: I've tried this one also. we can move the labels to the center and axis as well but that doesn't meet my requirement.